# Maximum $m$ verify $n+m$ coprime to primorial $q$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ and $q \geq 3$ a prime,

Suppose that $n$ coprime to $\displaystyle {\small\left(\prod_{\substack{a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)}$ , after many observations i think that exists $m$ verify $n+m$ coprime to $\displaystyle {\small\left(\prod_{\substack{a \leq q \\ \text{a prime}}} {\normalsize a} \right)}$ and $m < 2q$, i am not sure about this claim and i like to know if there are results about that ?

Comment: You are asking whether the Jacobsthal function $h(n)$ defined [here](https://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function) is smaller than $2p_n$. If I'm not mistaken, the values given in this link give that this is false for $p_n=43$, hence so is your conjecture for $q=43$.

Comment: Thanks, @Wojowu, and most possible that $h(n) > c p_n$ with $c$ arbiratery large.